# Why the realloc did not work properly in this case?

Tags: c, string, pointers, realloc

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char *func(char * str){


    int len;
    len=strlen(str)+3;
    str = (char *)realloc(str,len);
    return str;


}

void main(){

    printf("str:%s",func("hello"));

}
```

The final ans prints (null),instead of printing the string: "hello". Can anyone please explain why is it so?
I am unable to identify any error.
**Can anyone rectify the error, and help me with a working code. Please!**

Comment: `void main(){..` No wonder....

Comment: You call realloc on a char * that can't be realloced.  So it fails, and returns NULL.

Comment: The question is tagged `dynamic-allocation`, and yet there's none in sight... @WilliamPursell Shouldn't this generate a warning, or complete failure to compile, for passing a `char const *` (type of string literal) to `func()`? I mostly program C++14 with all warnings on, so maybe I'm too used to good type safety...

Comment: @underscore_d String literal is of type `char*`.

Comment: @2501 Then I guess that's a C thing. More's the pity. In C++, implicitly converting `char const *` to `char *` is still legal but deprecated, and many compilers will warn the programmer into oblivion for trying it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2760547/2757035 And rightly so! Any attempt to edit that [scare quotes] '`char *`' is UB, and too easy to try.

Comment: __Can anyone rectify the error, and help me with a working code. Please!__ Sorry, did you actually take ypour time to read the given answers? We're not here to write the code for you, we can only show you the way...

Comment: @underscore_d I don't get your point. You can't convert const to non-const in C without a cast either.

Comment: @2501 My point is that C++ is stricter and defines string literals as `char const *`, whereas C just uses `char *`. C++ is seemingly also dropping the ability to silently convert and drop the const.

Comment: @underscore_d  `C++ is seemingly also dropping the ability to silently convert and drop the const` There is no such feature in C. You can't convert const to non-const in C without a cast.

Comment: @2501 Please read again and let me know if I've misunderstood. In C, string literals are not `const`. In C++, they are `const` _but_ could be implicitly converted in contexts such as this. In C++, this is now strongly deprecated or even forbidden, depending on which compiler you ask.

Comment: [Don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your program invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because you're passing a pointer, which was not previously returned by dynamic memory allocator family of functions, to `realloc()`.

According to `C11`, chapter §7.22.3.5, *The realloc function*, (*emphasis mine*)

> If `ptr` is a null pointer, the `realloc` function behaves like the `malloc` function for the
>   specified size. Otherwise, **if `ptr` does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory
>   management function**, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to the `free` or
>   `realloc` function, **the behavior is undefined.** [...]

That said,

- For a hosted environment, `void main()` should better be `int main(void)`, at least.
- [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: @Anonymous [prefered way at stackoverflow to say "thanks"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/202811)

Answer (score 6):

`"hello"` is a **read-only** string *literal*. Its type is really a `const char*` although compilers allow assignment to a `char*` despite all the merry hell that this causes.

The behaviour on calling `realloc` on such a pointer is *undefined*. So the compiler can do anything it likes. It might eat your cat.

Answer (score 1):

You may realloc an object that was allocated dynamically. String literals have static storage duration and may not be changed. Any attempt to modify a string literal results in undefined behavior.

What you could do is the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *func( const char * str )
{
    size_t len = strlen( str ) + 3;

    char *tmp = realloc( NULL, len );

    if ( tmp ) strcpy( tmp, str );

    return tmp;
}

int main( void )
{
    char *str = func( "hello" );

    if ( str ) printf( "str: %s\n", str );

    free( str );
}
```

The program output is

```
str: hello
```

Take into account that the call

```
realloc( NULL, len )
```

is equivalent to

```
malloc( len )
```

Comment: `realloc ( NULL, len );` Why not just `malloc(len)`? They're equivalent, but the latter seems better semantically.

Comment: @underscore_d Because the question about realloc.