# This Pointer error No instance of constructor matches the argument list

Tags: c++, constructor, this-pointer

Please help error: no instance of constructor matches the argument list.
And also please help explain about "strcpy(this->name, name);"

```
class Student {
    char name[50];
    char surname[50];
    int age;
public:
    Student(char name[], char surname[], int age) {
        strcpy(this->name, name); // please explain this line what does it means?
        strcpy(this->surname, surname);
        this->age = age;
    }
    void Show() {
        cout << "Name: " << this->name << endl;
        cout << "Surname: " << this->surname << endl;
        cout << "Age: " << this->age;
    }
};

int main() {
    Student A("Ivan", "Sidoroff", 25);
    A.Show();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760500/why-is-passing-a-string-literal-into-a-char-argument-only-sometimes-a-compiler

Comment: 1) The code, that you show, [compiles just fine](https://ideone.com/DWl68A). 2) What `strcpy` does is explained in the documentation of [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius You need to turn up your warnings then *ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *'*

Comment: @NathanOliver I thought that on C++11 and later this is an error, and not a warning, and since I compiled with C++14, I thought that if there were any such errors, it wouldn't compile. :/ Curse you g++, and your non-standard extensions!

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius If it help I always use `-Wall -pedantic` when compiling.  I also use Wandbox or coliru as you can actually specify all the options and see all the warnings.

Comment: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic` ftw

Answer (score 2):

> Please help error: no instance of constructor matches the argument
>   list.

Instead of this:

```
Student(char name[], char surname[], int age) {
```

Try this:

```
Student(const char *name, const char *surname, int age) {
```

It complains because the `char` pointers aren't matching the pointers to `const char`.

> `strcpy(this->name, name);` // please explain this line what does it
>   means?

It copies the string from `name` (the parameter passed) to the other `name` (that is part of `class Student`). Since both are called `name` it's ambiguous. In this case, `name` refers to the parameter, and `this->name` is used to refer to the field in the `class Student` instead.

More generally, `this` is a pointer to the object calling the function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I have tried your code, it did fine, but in addition it need to change from strcpy to strcpy_s. it work now.

Comment: thanks for your explain on strcpy also... in order to avoid ambiguous, I remember my teacher's lesson to use underscore: _name (the parameter passed).