# Can a string literal be passed to a function that takes const char*?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, implicit-conversion, user-defined-literals

I need help understanding some code.

I have read in [other places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760500/) that passing a *string literal* as a `const char*` is legal.  But, in the last line of [this code from cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) for user-defined string literals, it says that there is no literal operator for `"two"`. Why is that, if the string literal `"two"` can be passed to the function taking `const char*`?

```
long double operator "" _w(long double);
std::string operator "" _w(const char16_t*, size_t);
unsigned operator "" _w(const char*);


int main() {
    1.2_w; // calls operator "" _w(1.2L)

    u"one"_w; // calls operator "" _w(u"one", 3)

    12_w; // calls operator "" _w("12")

    "two"_w; // error: no applicable literal operator
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a user-defined literal operator that works on a character string *must* have two parameters: a pointer to the characters, and a length (see section `3b` in your cppreference link).  The example operator you think should be called lacks this length parameter.

For it to work, the declaration should be

```
unsigned operator "" _w(const char*, size_t);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can a string literal be passed to a function that takes const char*?

Yes.

An example:

```
void foo(const char*);
foo("two"); // works
```

You've linked to and quoted the documentation of *user defined string literals*. *User defined string literals* are a separate thing from *string literals*.

> but in the last line of this code from cppeference for user defined string literals, it says that there is no literal operator for "two".

Correction: There is no user defined string literal for `_w` in the example. `"two"` is a string literal. `"two"_w` is a user defined string literal, but since there is no declaration for `T operator "" _w(const char*, size_t)` in the example, that is an error.

> Why is that if the string literal "two" can be passed to the function taking const char*?

Whether `"two"` can be passed into a function taking `const char*` is completely separate from whether you have defined a user defined string literal.